# Kotlin, Spring, mybatisでのForeachがうまくいかない

Tags: spring, kotlin

kotlin, spring-boot, mybaticでのForeachの処置がうまくいかないです。

以下のSQLを実行しても "#{id} が見つかりません" というエラーになってしまいます。どなたかご教授願えますと幸いです。

具体的なエラーメッセージ

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found. Available parameters are [orderIds, param1]
```

実行したSQL

```
@Select(
    """
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            order
        WHERE 
            order_id IN 
        <foreach item="id" collection="orderIds" open="(" separator="," close=")" >
            #{id}
        </foreach>
    """
)
fun findByOrderIds(@Param(value = "orderIds") orderIds: List<String>): Int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`script` タグ](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/ja/dynamic-sql.html#script) で囲う必要があります:

```kotlin
    @Select(
        """
            <script>
                SELECT 
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM 
                    `order`
                <where>
                    <foreach item="id" collection="orderIds" open="order_id IN (" separator="," close=")" >
                        #{id}
                    </foreach>
                </where>
            </script>
        """
    )
    fun findByOrderIds(@Param(value = "orderIds") orderIds: List<String>): Int
```